# Photoview ondraw

Tags: android, view, ondraw, android-photoview

I am kind of new to the onDraw so i don't know how to go around this problem.

I want to draw a image at this location (just so i can try the rest myself). These locations are off the ontap and * the drawables width and height. This code is in a class that extends photoview.

The problem is this resource is not being displayed, i also tried to use on a drawcirlce example that also didnt display. I have also attached that below.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Bitmap markerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.markerformap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(markerBitmap, 2000, 5000, new Paint());
}
```

Draw circle example

```
    canvas.drawCircle(2000, 5000,300, new Paint());
```

The onTouch Listener

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(y != event.getY() && x != event.getX()){
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: change `2000, 5000` - > `0, 0` and check again

Comment: @pskink it loads fine in the top right, i dont know how to solve the problem though

Comment: so what is your problem actually? why you use `2000, 5000` ? what do you really want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink  want the ontap to display a image on top of where the person tapped. The numbers were the ontap x* width of bitmap and y* height of bitmap. The numbers were there just to see if it would even display.

Comment: so if you use `0, 0` it displays, now what? instead of `2000, 5000` use `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`

Comment: i am using onPhotoTap which doesn't recognize that method. Should i not use the floats given in that method?

Comment: it does not have `onTouchEvent` ?

Comment: No, i am using this one https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/photoview/src/main/java/com/github/chrisbanes/photoview/OnPhotoTapListener.java.

Comment: just override `onTouchEvent` and store the event position somewhere

Comment: @pskink I have added my ontouch to the code in the main question. I have also stored them and its called in a if statemet to see if it was the same as previous and if so doesn't create a new one. Shamefully is still doesnt work and it is called in the constructor.